# scrappy install on centOS getting strange error

Tags: python, scrapy

I installed scrappy on centos 5.0

I am getting the following error:

```
dependency not found: LXML installed but misconfigured.
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install libxslt, use: sudo port install libxslt . Now, just type pip install lxml , it should work fine. before compiling add the path that to xmlversion.h into your environment. Then used command line easy_install to install the .egg file